# Problem with SMFL Syntax in C++ Visual Studio importing png

Tags: c++, visual-studio, png, sfml

-I am new to C++ and SFML and want to import a png file.

-It worked a view times, but afterwards I got the
message "Build failed, run last success?" most of the time. Sometimes its still working.

-there is no "real" error, so its hard to figure out, what the problem is

-I read earlier, that switching from Debug to Release-Mode could be a reason, but it didnt helped

- its working when I dont use:

```
if (!texture.loadFromFile("assets/player.png")) 
        {
        std::cout << "Could not load png \n";
        return 0;
        }
```

-> but, ofcourse, the sprite is missing then.

I would be happy to have a solution/reason for this or a topic I missed so far to read/ learn about.
Im happy about advices.
Thanks so far.

Alex

VISUAL STUDIO 2019
x64
SFML-2.5.1

---

WHOLE CODE:

```
#include"SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include"main.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1200,800), "bimWindow");
    sf::RectangleShape rs(sf::Vector2f(1000, 700));
    rs.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::Event event;
    sf::Texture texture;

    if (!texture.loadFromFile("assets/player.png")) 
        {
        std::cout << "Could not load png \n";
        return 0;
        }

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(100,100);
    //sprite.scale(sf::Vector2f(3, 3));

    rs.setPosition(80, 80);

    // run the program as long as the window is open:
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        
        //let window open i guess.
        while (window.pollEvent(event)); //stay true as long aas it didnt happen or so
        {
            // "close requested" event:close the window
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
        }
        //RENDER:
        window.clear();
        window.draw(rs);
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the "assets/player.png" file is inside your solution directory (the folder with the .sln file.) Your code seems to run fine on my end, and that is the only error I can think of. If you can, it would help to have the error message(s) that you are receiving. If the png file is in the right place and you still get errors, I would recommend reinstalling SFML and following a tutorial online to ensure that you get everything set up properly.